# how to apply one hot encoding or get dummies on 2 columns together in pandas?

Tags: pandas, one-hot-encoding

I have below dataframe which contain sample values like:-

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["London", "Cambridge", 20], ["Cambridge", "London", 10], ["Liverpool", "London", 30]], columns= ["city_1", "city_2", "id"])

city_1     city_2        id
London     Cambridge     20
Cambridge  London        10
Liverpool  London        30
```

I need the output dataframe as below which is built while joining 2 city columns together and applying one hot encoding after that:

```
id London Cambridge Liverpool
20 1       1        0
10 1       1        0
30 1       0        1
```

Currently, I am using the below code which works one time on a column, please could you advise if there is any pythonic way to get the above output

```
output_df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['city_1', 'city_2'])
```

which results in

```
id city_1_Cambridge city_1_London and so on columns
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add parameters `prefix_sep` and `prefix` to [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) and then use `max` if want only `1` or `0` values (dummies or indicator columns) or `sum` if need count `1` values :

```
output_df = (pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['city_1', 'city_2'], prefix_sep='', prefix='')
               .max(axis=1, level=0))
print (output_df)
   id  Cambridge  Liverpool  London
0  20          1          0       1
1  10          1          0       1
2  30          0          1       1
```

Or if want processing all columns without `id` convert not processing column(s) to index first by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), then use `get_dummies` with `max` and last add [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
output_df = (pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('id'), prefix_sep='', prefix='')
               .max(axis=1, level=0)
               .reset_index())
print (output_df)
   id  Cambridge  Liverpool  London
0  20          1          0       1
1  10          1          0       1
2  30          0          1       1
```